# How can I speed this loop up? Is there a class for replacing multiple terms at at time?

Tags: c#, string, optimization, replace

The loop:

```
var pattern = _dict[key];
string before;
do
{
    before = pattern;
    foreach (var pair in _dict)
        if (key != pair.Key)
            pattern = pattern.Replace(string.Concat("{", pair.Key, "}"), string.Concat("(", pair.Value, ")"));
} while (pattern != before);
return pattern;
```

It just does a repeated find-and-replace on a bunch of keys. The dictionary is just `<string,string>`.

I can see 2 improvements to this.

1. Every time we do `pattern.Replace` it searches from the beginning of the string again. It would be better if when it hit the first `{`, it would just look through the list of keys for a match (perhaps using a binary search), and then replace the appropriate one.
2. The `pattern != before` bit is how I check if anything was replaced during that iteration. If the `pattern.Replace` function returned how many or if any replaces actually occured, I wouldn't need this.

However... I don't really want to write a big nasty thing class to do all that. This must be a fairly common scenario? Are there any existng solutions?

---

## Full Class

Thanks to **Elian Ebbing** and **ChrisWue**.

```
class FlexDict : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private static readonly Regex _re = new Regex(@"{([_a-z][_a-z0-9-]*)}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public void Add(string key, string pattern)
    {
        _dict[key] = pattern;
    }

    public string Expand(string pattern)
    {
        pattern = _re.Replace(pattern, match =>
            {
                string key = match.Groups[1].Value;

                if (_dict.ContainsKey(key))
                    return "(" + Expand(_dict[key]) + ")";

                return match.Value;
            });

        return pattern;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return Expand(_dict[key]); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var p in _dict)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(p.Key, this[p.Key]);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

## Example Usage

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var flex = new FlexDict
            {
                {"h", @"[0-9a-f]"},
                {"nonascii", @"[\200-\377]"},
                {"unicode", @"\\{h}{1,6}(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?"},
                {"escape", @"{unicode}|\\[^\r\n\f0-9a-f]"},
                {"nmstart", @"[_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}"},
                {"nmchar", @"[_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}"},
                {"string1", @"""([^\n\r\f\\""]|\\{nl}|{escape})*"""},
                {"string2", @"'([^\n\r\f\\']|\\{nl}|{escape})*'"},
                {"badstring1", @"""([^\n\r\f\\""]|\\{nl}|{escape})*\\?"},
                {"badstring2", @"'([^\n\r\f\\']|\\{nl}|{escape})*\\?"},
                {"badcomment1", @"/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*"},
                {"badcomment2", @"/\*[^*]*(\*+[^/*][^*]*)*"},
                {"baduri1", @"url\({w}([!#$%&*-\[\]-~]|{nonascii}|{escape})*{w}"},
                {"baduri2", @"url\({w}{string}{w}"},
                {"baduri3", @"url\({w}{badstring}"},
                {"comment", @"/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/"},
                {"ident", @"-?{nmstart}{nmchar}*"},
                {"name", @"{nmchar}+"},
                {"num", @"[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+"},
                {"string", @"{string1}|{string2}"},
                {"badstring", @"{badstring1}|{badstring2}"},
                {"badcomment", @"{badcomment1}|{badcomment2}"},
                {"baduri", @"{baduri1}|{baduri2}|{baduri3}"},
                {"url", @"([!#$%&*-~]|{nonascii}|{escape})*"},
                {"s", @"[ \t\r\n\f]+"},
                {"w", @"{s}?"},
                {"nl", @"\n|\r\n|\r|\f"},

                {"A", @"a|\\0{0,4}(41|61)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?"},
                {"C", @"c|\\0{0,4}(43|63)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?"},
                {"D", @"d|\\0{0,4}(44|64)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?"},
                {"E", @"e|\\0{0,4}(45|65)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?"},
                {"G", @"g|\\0{0,4}(47|67)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\g"},
                {"H", @"h|\\0{0,4}(48|68)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\h"},
                {"I", @"i|\\0{0,4}(49|69)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\i"},
                {"K", @"k|\\0{0,4}(4b|6b)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\k"},
                {"L", @"l|\\0{0,4}(4c|6c)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\l"},
                {"M", @"m|\\0{0,4}(4d|6d)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\m"},
                {"N", @"n|\\0{0,4}(4e|6e)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\n"},
                {"O", @"o|\\0{0,4}(4f|6f)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\o"},
                {"P", @"p|\\0{0,4}(50|70)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\p"},
                {"R", @"r|\\0{0,4}(52|72)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\r"},
                {"S", @"s|\\0{0,4}(53|73)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\s"},
                {"T", @"t|\\0{0,4}(54|74)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\t"},
                {"U", @"u|\\0{0,4}(55|75)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\u"},
                {"X", @"x|\\0{0,4}(58|78)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\x"},
                {"Z", @"z|\\0{0,4}(5a|7a)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\z"},
                {"Z", @"z|\\0{0,4}(5a|7a)(\r\n|[ \t\r\n\f])?|\\z"},

                {"CDO", @"<!--"},
                {"CDC", @"-->"},
                {"INCLUDES", @"~="},
                {"DASHMATCH", @"\|="},
                {"STRING", @"{string}"},
                {"BAD_STRING", @"{badstring}"},
                {"IDENT", @"{ident}"},
                {"HASH", @"#{name}"},
                {"IMPORT_SYM", @"@{I}{M}{P}{O}{R}{T}"},
                {"PAGE_SYM", @"@{P}{A}{G}{E}"},
                {"MEDIA_SYM", @"@{M}{E}{D}{I}{A}"},
                {"CHARSET_SYM", @"@charset\b"},
                {"IMPORTANT_SYM", @"!({w}|{comment})*{I}{M}{P}{O}{R}{T}{A}{N}{T}"},
                {"EMS", @"{num}{E}{M}"},
                {"EXS", @"{num}{E}{X}"},
                {"LENGTH", @"{num}({P}{X}|{C}{M}|{M}{M}|{I}{N}|{P}{T}|{P}{C})"},
                {"ANGLE", @"{num}({D}{E}{G}|{R}{A}{D}|{G}{R}{A}{D})"},
                {"TIME", @"{num}({M}{S}|{S})"},
                {"PERCENTAGE", @"{num}%"},
                {"NUMBER", @"{num}"},
                {"URI", @"{U}{R}{L}\({w}{string}{w}\)|{U}{R}{L}\({w}{url}{w}\)"},
                {"BAD_URI", @"{baduri}"},
                {"FUNCTION", @"{ident}\("},
            };

        var testStrings = new[] { @"""str""", @"'str'", "5", "5.", "5.0", "a", "alpha", "url(hello)", 
            "url(\"hello\")", "url(\"blah)", @"\g", @"/*comment*/", @"/**/", @"<!--", @"-->", @"~=",
            "|=", @"#hash", "@import", "@page", "@media", "@charset", "!/*iehack*/important"};

        foreach (var pair in flex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n\t{1}\n", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        foreach (var str in testStrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} matches: ", str);
            foreach (var pair in flex)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "^(" + pair.Value + ")$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture))
                    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", pair.Key);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nRan in {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

## Purpose

For building complex regular expressions that may extend eachother. Namely, I'm trying to implement [the css spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it would be faster if you look for any occurrences of `{foo}` using a regular expression, and then use a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) that replaces the `{foo}` if `foo` happens to be a key in the dictionary.

I have currently no visual studio here, but I guess this is functionally equivalent with your code example:

```
var pattern = _dict[key];
bool isChanged = false;

do
{
    isChanged = false;

    pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, "{([^}]+)}", match => {
        string matchKey = match.Groups[1].Value;

        if (matchKey != key && _dict.ContainsKey(matchKey))
        {
            isChanged = true;
            return "(" + _dict[matchKey] + ")";
        }

        return match.Value;
    });
} while (isChanged);
```

Can I ask you why you need the do/while loop? Can the value of a key in the dictionary again contain `{placeholders}` that have to be replaced? Can you be sure you don't get stuck in an infinite loop where key `"A"` contains `"Blahblah {B}"` and key `"B"` contains `"Blahblah {A}"`?

Edit: further improvements would be:

- Using a precompiled Regex.
- Using recursion instead of a loop (see [ChrisWue's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220986/chriswue) comment).
- Using `_dict.TryGetValue()`, as in [Guffa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) code.

You will end up with an O(n) algorithm where n is the size of the output, so you can't do much better than this.

Comment: Yes, the value contain other `{placeholders}`. No, I can't be sure I won't get stuck in an infinite loop... the `key != pair.Key` was supposed to prevent that (replacing w/ itself anyway), but as you pointed out, it can be caused in other ways. I'm not too worried though... if an infinite loop is created, it should become quickly apparent.

Comment: A further improvement might be to make it recursive instead of a loop. Assuming the above replacement code is a function called Replace(s, re, dict) then do 'return "(" + Replace(_dict[matchKey], re, _dict) + ")"' Depending on the amount of nesting and the length of the source string this might improve things further. Would have the "advantage" of running in a stackoverflow instead of an infinite loop. Also pre compiling the regular expression could help.

Comment: @ChrisWue: I don't think I can make it recursive like that (see updated question). The way I have it set up, it just returns the pattern for a particular key, but it won't accept an input string... actually.. with a few modifications I can do that. Updating Q again.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a regular expression to find the matches. Then you can also make use of the fast lookup of the dictionary and not just use it as a list.

```
var pattern = _dict[key];
bool replaced = false;
do {
  pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\{([^\}]+)\}", m => {
    string k = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string value;
    if (k != key && _dict.TryGetValue(k, out value) {
      replaced = true;
      return "(" + value + ")";
    } else {
      return "{" + k + "}";
    }
  });
} while (replaced);
return pattern;
```

Comment: Cool how we both wrote almost the same code :-). BTW, you forgot to reset `replaced` to `false` at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the following algorithm:

1. Search for `{` in source string
2. Copy everything upto `{` to StringBuilder
3. Find matching `}` (the search is done from last fond position)
4. Compare value between `{` and `}` to keys in your dictionary
5. - If it matches copy to String builder `(` + `Value` + `)`
   - Else copy from source string
6. If source string end is not reached go to step 1

Answer (score -1):

Could you use PLINQ at all?

Something along the lines of:

```
var keys = dict.KeyCollection.Where(k => k != key);
bool replacementMade = keys.Any();

foreach(var k in keys.AsParallel(), () => {replacement code})
```